# Using @Embedded in @Embeddable class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Can I use @Embedded in @Embeddable class in hibernate.

Example :
A is an element collection in a diffirent class.

```
@Embeddable
class A {

    @Embedded
    B b;
}

@Embeddable
class B {

    @Embedded
    C c;
}


@Embeddable
class C {

    @Embedded
    D D;
}

@Embeddable
class D {



}
```

Is something of this kind valid in hibernate ? The third level of nesting.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is valid in Hibernate to nest `@Embedded` objects.

Directly from the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#embeddable-objects) :

> Embeddable types can be nested. That is, an @Embeddable class may have an attribute whose type is itself a different @Embeddable class.

For example, from the [specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/embeddable) :

```java
@Embeddable public class Address {
   protected String street;
   protected String city;
   protected String state;
   @Embedded protected Zipcode zipcode;
}

@Embeddable public class Zipcode {
   protected String zip;
   protected String plusFour;
}
```

Comment: I'm able to get upto the second level of nesting is third level of nesting valid. My issue is i'm unable to rename the thrid level parameters with attributeoveride of columns. Thanks for replying !

Comment: Hmm, are your column names duplicated?

Comment: No, They are different in class D

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by johncarl, it is possible. In order to rename nested attributes you have to specify the entire chain, using '.' as separator. For example, if class D has an attribute *foo*, then in class A you would need to rename it as such:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverride(name = "c.D.foo", column = @Column(name = "bar"))
B b;
```